# Associate information boxes with image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a situation, I have an image of human body that would allow a user to click on any part of the image and an information box should pop out to take information from user and then save it to database. All information boxes should be edit able.
 If anyone knows about any plugin or any suggestion please let me know. For more understanding I have attached an image. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Sorry mate I don't have any information related to this and nothing I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should give [kineticjs](http://kineticjs.com/) a try.You can check this [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-interactive-building-map/) in which we attach labels to certain parts of the picture you just need to feed the points.You can hide the labels if you want to or highlight the area of concern on some events if you want.Hope that helps.